# Actionscript 2.0, BitmapData and Local vs Remote images

Tags: php, database, flash, security, actionscript-2

Good Morning Justice League of Stackoverflow,

I have here a problem that may stump the panel.

I am creating an interactive post-it for an upcoming event that allows for us to tap into a sql database and post tweets, survey answers and images.  We've already tapped into the Twitter API and the survey, so those are A-OK.

The problem lies within loading the images from a location other than the local interactive board's server.

If the image itself is locally hosted, it loads just fine.
If the image is hosted elsewhere, the image will not load, even though I have a trace on the URL of said image.

I'm loading all tweets, surveys and images through an XML load and all the data is loading properly.

I AM loading the image through a smoothing filter so that when the "post-its" are slightly rotated, they are not jagged.  Here is THAT code:

```
import flash.display.*;

var srcImg = _parent._parent.varContent;
urlText.text = srcImg;
var mainHolder = this.createEmptyMovieClip("main", this.getNextHighestDepth());
var original = mainHolder.createEmptyMovieClip("original", mainHolder.getNextHighestDepth());
var smooth = mainHolder.createEmptyMovieClip("smooth", mainHolder.getNextHighestDepth());
var mclListener:Object = new Object();
mclListener.onLoadInit = function() {
    var w = original._width;
    var h = original._height;
    var bmpData1:BitmapData = new BitmapData(w, h, true, 0x000000);//true and 0 color allows for transparency
    bmpData1.draw(original);
    smooth.attachBitmap(bmpData1,2,"auto",true);//true for SMOOTHING, ;)
    reSize(smooth);
    original.removeMovieClip();
    mainHolder._x = -(smooth._width / 2);
    mainHolder._y = -(smooth._height / 2);
};
var image_mcl:MovieClipLoader = new MovieClipLoader();
image_mcl.addListener(mclListener);
image_mcl.loadClip(srcImg,original);

function reSize(target) {
    if (target._width > target._height) {
        s = Math.floor((300.85 / target._height) * 100);
    }

    if (target._width < target._height) {
        s = Math.floor((320.90 / target._width) * 100);
    }
    target._xscale = s;
    target._yscale = s;
}
```

This is a two part script where the bulk loads in the image and places it into an empty movieclip, then adds the smoothing filter.  The second part is a resizer that automatically resizes the image and keeps the aspect ratio

Here's the kicker.  When I test the flash piece (not embedded in HTML) the thing works 100%.
As soon as I put the swf into an html and view it on a web page, the remote images will not load.

I'm a bit stumped on why this is, could this be a firewall or security issue?  Because I work in a high security firewall environment.

Any guidance in this would be most appreciated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have crossdomain access to the images you are loading? If you do not, then trying to perform bitmap operations will not work.

Comment: where do I find out if I do or do not have crossdomain access?

Comment: its a bitmap data security thing I think. The second part of this article should help: http://www.onegiantmedia.com/as3---load-a-remote-image-from-any-domain-with-no-security-sandbox-errors

Comment: If you download the Debug version of Flash Player you should see the security errors in your browser: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default flash does not allow cross domain loading of data as a security feature, but it can be overridden.

this may help:
allowDomain (security.allowDomain method) if you can get a swf running on the image server

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/main/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Parts&file=00002104.html

A cross domain policy file may also be used on the server to grant access to the swf:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000470.html

Comment: OK... say this application is hosted on a public server, and all the images I need to load are FTP'd to this same box, I wouldn't need to worry about any of this security stuff, correct?

Comment: as long as the images are on the same domain, there should be no security limitations.